# Create a "redirect" auth activity

Tags: android

I have a `MainActivity` that does a call to my web server to find out if the `user` is logged in. When the call is finished I have two options: (1) the user is logged in and the `TabsActivity` is opened; (2) the user is not logged in and the `LoginActivity` is opened.

When the user is "redirected" to the `TabsActivity` and presses the Home button and then goes back to the app, the `MainActivity` opens again. How can I make sure the `TabsActivity` is opened?

```
protected void startLoginActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
}

protected void startTabsActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" flag, the activity is destroyed when it is left (which could be a new navigation, or suspending the app / pressing home).

If you need an alternative "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" logic, you need call "finish()" for that specific activity when you no longer need it.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: no probs :) Would have been more nice to have a "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY_WHEN_NOT_ON_TOP_OF_STACK"